# Download and upload image without saving to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-uploading, fs

Using Node.js, I am trying to get an image from a URL and upload that image to another service without saving image to disk. I have the following code that works when saving the file to disk and using fs to create a readablestream. But as I am doing this as a cron job on a read-only file system (webtask.io) I'd want to achieve the same result without saving the file to disk temporarily. Shouldn't that be possible?

```
  request(image.Url)
  .pipe(
    fs
      .createWriteStream(image.Id)
      .on('finish', () => {
        client.assets
          .upload('image', fs.createReadStream(image.Id))
          .then(imageAsset => {
            resolve(imageAsset)
          })
      })
    )
```

Do you have any suggestions of how to achieve this without saving the file to disk? The upload client will take the following

```
client.asset.upload(type: 'file' | image', body: File | Blob | Buffer | NodeStream, options = {}): Promise<AssetDocument>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the buffer down to the upload function? Since as per your statement it'll accept a buffer.

As a side note... This will keep it in memory for the duration of the method execution, so if you call this numerous times you might run out of resources.

```
request.get(url, function (res) {
      var data = [];

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', function() {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
        // Pass the buffer
        client.asset.upload(type: 'buffer', body: buffer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some various libraries and it turns out that [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch) provides a way to return a buffer. So this code works:

```
  fetch(image.Url)
    .then(res => res.buffer())
    .then(buffer => client.assets
      .upload('image', buffer, {filename: image.Id}))
      .then(imageAsset => {
        resolve(imageAsset)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

well I know it has been a few years since the question was originally asked,
 but I have encountered this problem now, and since I didn't find an answer with a comprehensive example I made one myself.
i'm assuming that the file path is a valid URL and that the end of it is the file name, 
I need to pass an apikey to this API endpoint, and a successful upload sends me back a response with a token. 
I'm using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) as dependencies.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const secretKey = 'secretKey';

const downloadAndUploadFile = async (filePath) => {
const fileName = new URL(filePath).pathname.split("/").pop();
const endpoint = `the-upload-endpoint-url`;
const formData = new FormData();
let jsonResponse = null;
try {
    const download = await fetch(filePath);
    const buffer = await download.buffer();
    if (!buffer) {
        console.log('file not found', filePath);
        return null;
    }
    formData.append('file', buffer, fileName);
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST', body: formData, headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${secretKey}`,
        },
    });
    jsonResponse = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error on file upload', error);
    }
    return jsonResponse ? jsonResponse.token : null;
}
```